# SVG Circle progress, how to start the meter at the top?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm working to build a SVG Circle progress meter.

In the snippet below. I show the meter rendering 20% complete. The problem is I need the meter to start at the top center, not like it is current at 90degress. How can I get the SVG circle progress meter to start at the top/center of the circle?

```css
  #svg circle {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s linear;
    stroke: #311321;
    stroke-width: 1em;
  }
  #svg #bar {
    stroke: red ;
  }
  #cont {
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 2em auto;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: relative;
  }
  #cont:after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 160px;
    width: 160px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    content: attr(data-pct)"%";
    margin-top: -80px;
    margin-left: -80px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    line-height: 160px;
    font-size: 2em;
  }
```

```html
<div id="cont" data-pct="20">
   <svg id="svg" width="200" height="200" viewPort="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <circle r="90" cx="100" cy="100" fill="transparent" stroke-dasharray="565.48" stroke-dashoffset="0"></circle>
      <circle id="bar" r="90" cx="100" cy="100" fill="transparent" stroke-dasharray="565.48" stroke-dashoffset="0" style="stroke-dashoffset: 452.389;"></circle>
   </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I would put the 2 circles in a group and rotate the group `<g transform="rotate(-90 100 100)">`

Comment: Also viewPort won't do anything, did you mean viewBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transform='rotate(-90 100 100)'` on `#bar` circle to start it from top.

See below Snippet:

```css
#svg circle {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s linear;
    stroke: #311321;
    stroke-width: 1em;
  }
  #svg #bar {
    stroke: red ;
  }
  #cont {
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 2em auto;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: relative;
  }
  #cont:after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 160px;
    width: 160px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    content: attr(data-pct)"%";
    margin-top: -80px;
    margin-left: -80px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    line-height: 160px;
    font-size: 2em;
  }
```

```html
<div id="cont" data-pct="20">
   <svg id="svg" width="200" height="200" viewPort="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <circle r="90" cx="100" cy="100" fill="transparent" stroke-dasharray="565.48" stroke-dashoffset="0"></circle>
      <circle id="bar" r="90" cx="100" cy="100" fill="transparent" stroke-dasharray="565.48" stroke-dashoffset="0" style="stroke-dashoffset: 452.389;" transform='rotate(-90 100 100)'></circle>
   </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I found is to set

```
transform: rotate(-90deg);
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
```

to circle#bar and to set **NEGATIVE** `stroke-dashoffset`, that way it draws the circle from the top and counter-clockwise just as I needed.